# Extracting information from a nested DB-Config file accross various tables

Tags: typescript, function, generics

I have been stuck on this problem for so long and can´t seem to find an answer. So maybe any of you nice people can help.

I have a db-config file in the following form:

```
const simpleDbConfig: DbConfig = {
    firstTable: {
        columns: {
            foo1: { jsName: "foo1", nameDb : "Foo1", dataType: "TEXT" },
            bar1: { jsName: "bar1", nameDb: "Bar1", dataType: "TEXT" },
        },
    },
     secondTable: {
        columns: {
            foo2: { jsName: "foo2", nameDb: "Foo2", dataType: "TEXT" },
            bar2: { jsName: "bar2", nameDb: "Bar2", dataType: "TEXT" },
        },
    },
};
```

And also the following type definitions:

```
type ColNamesFirst = "foo1" | "bar1";
type ColNamesSecond = "foo2" | "bar2";

type AllColNames = ColNamesFirst | ColNamesSecond;

interface DbConfig {
    firstTable: DbTable<ColNamesFirst>;
    secondTable: DbTable<ColNamesSecond>;
}

interface DbTable<T extends string> {
    columns: ColumnObject<T>;
}

type ColumnObject<T extends string> = Record<T, Column<T>>;

interface Column<T> {
    jsName: T;
    nameDb: string;
    dataType: string;
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is write a function, that accepts a record as input parameter. Possible keys are all keys of DbConfig. The corresponding values are arrays of any possible key of ColumnObject for the provided key of DbConfig. In the first step, the function should return a record containing all provided ColumnObject keys as keys. The values are supposed to be the corresponding columns. In a second step it would be nice if one could provide a property of Column as an argument whose value is to serve as keys for the return record.

Here is what I got so far:

```
export function getColumnConfigs<T extends keyof DbConfig, K extends keyof DbConfig[T]['columns']>(input: Record<T, K[]>): Record<K, DbConfig[T]['columns'][K]> {
    const result = {} as Record<K, DbConfig[T]['columns'][K]>;
  
    for (const key of Object.keys(input) as T[]) {
      const table = simpleDbConfig[key] as DbTable<AllColNames>;
      const columns = table.columns as Record<K, Column<K>>;
  
      for (const columnName of input[key]) {
        const column = columns[columnName] as DbConfig[T]['columns'][K]; 
        result[columnName] = column; 
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is how I would like to call the function and the desired output:

```
const res = getColumnConfigs({"firstTable": ["bar1"], "secondTable": ["foo2"]});


// desired output
res = {
    bar1: { jsName: "bar1", nameDb: "Bar1", dataType: "TEXT" },
    foo2: { jsName: "foo2", nameDb: "Foo2", dataType: "TEXT" }
}
```

For now it is not working. The provided arrays have the type never, as there are only values possible occuring in every ColumObject as keys.

Any suggestions on how I could fix this?

Thanks for your time and help!

- googled numerous things regarding union types, type casting, generics
- had a long discussion with chatgpt but solutions didn´t meet my needs
- stuck for a long time